# broken references with the new nature class

Tags: natbib, springer

I am using the new nature class from Springer, that is available on [this link](https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support).

I am having trouble figuring out how the references work, at the moment I always get an error that they are undefined. I created a reproducible example, and I would much appreciate any help. I build the file with PdfLaTex, but other engines also don't work.

This is how my main document looks like:

```
%%\documentclass[referee,sn-basic]{sn-jnl}% referee option is meant for double line spacing

%%=======================================================%%
%% to print line numbers in the margin use lineno option %%
%%=======================================================%%

%%\documentclass[lineno,sn-basic]{sn-jnl}% Basic Springer Nature Reference Style/Chemistry Reference Style

%%======================================================%%
%% to compile with pdflatex/xelatex use pdflatex option %%
%%======================================================%%

%%\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-basic]{sn-jnl}% Basic Springer Nature Reference Style/Chemistry Reference Style

%%\documentclass[sn-basic]{sn-jnl}% Basic Springer Nature Reference Style/Chemistry Reference Style
%%\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Reference Style
%%\documentclass[sn-aps]{sn-jnl}% American Physical Society (APS) Reference Style
%%\documentclass[sn-vancouver]{sn-jnl}% Vancouver Reference Style
%%\documentclass[sn-apa]{sn-jnl}% APA Reference Style
\documentclass[sn-chicago]{sn-jnl}% Chicago-based Humanities Reference Style
%%\documentclass[sn-standardnature]{sn-jnl}% Standard Nature Portfolio Reference Style
%%\documentclass[default]{sn-jnl}% Default
%%\documentclass[default,iicol]{sn-jnl}% Default with double column layout

%%%% Standard Packages
%%<additional latex packages if required can be included here>


\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }

\newcommand{\fignote}[1]{\small{\emph{Note:~}}#1\par}

%%%%


\jyear{2021}%

%% as per the requirement new theorem styles can be included as shown below
\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%  meant for continuous numbers
%%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]% meant for sectionwise numbers
%% optional argument [theorem] produces theorem numbering sequence instead of independent numbers for Proposition
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}% 
%%\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}% to get separate numbers for theorem and proposition etc.

\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}%
\newtheorem{example}{Example}%
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}%

\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}%
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}%

\raggedbottom
%%\unnumbered% uncomment this for unnumbered level heads

\begin{document}

\title[Some Title]{Some Title}

\subtitle{Some Subtitle}

\author*[1]{\fnm{My} \sur{Name}}\email{email@email.com}

\affil*[1]{\orgdiv{Org}, \orgname{Uni}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{00000}, \country{Neverland}}}


%%==================================%%
%% sample for unstructured abstract %%
%%==================================%%

\abstract{The paper abstract would come here}


\keywords{Random, Key, Words}

\maketitle


\section{Introduction}

As previous literature has shown \citep[][]{hutter_2014, aelst_walgrave_2001}.

\bibliography{bibliography.bib}% common bib file
%% if required, the content of .bbl file can be included here once bbl is generated
%%\input sn-article.bbl

%% Default %%
%%\input sn-sample-bib.tex%

\end{document}
```

And this is bibliography.bib:

```
@book{hutter_2014,
    address = "Minneapolis",
    title = "Protesting Culture and Economics in Western Europe",
    publisher = "University of Minnesota Press",
    author = "Hutter, Swen",
    year = "2014"}
    
@article{aelst_walgrave_2001,
    title = "Who is that (wo)man in the street? From the normalisation of protest to the normalisation of the protester",
    volume = "39",
    shorttitle = "Who is that (wo)man in the street?",
    number = "4",
    doi="10.1111/1475-6765.00582",
    journal = "European Journal of Political Research",
    author = "Aelst, Peter Van and Walgrave, Stefaan",
    year = "2001",
    pages = "461--486"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you downloaded `Download+the+journal+article+template+package` from the link, added the `.zip` missing (!)  and  extracted the files, you will find a subdirectory `bst`. Find inside `sn-chicago.bst`. Copy this file to your working directory.

After running `bibtex` compile *twice* to get:

[image: a]